# ASP.NET C# serialize HttpValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I'm trying to serialize a Request object for logging purposes. The code

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
// obj is a Request object
```

gives me the following exception:

```
To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add(System.String) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. System.Web.HttpValueCollection does not implement Add(System.String).
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: what Type is obj ? is it your type ?

Comment: In title you are saying that you are trying to serialize HttpValueCollection and in description you are saying Request (HttpRequest?). Can you be more clear about your question?

Answer (score 1):

In short, trying to serialize a http request object may not end well; even if you get past the current issue, I would expect it to fail in a few more places.

You should construct **your own** object model that includes those parts of the request you care about, in a simple form. In the case of the HttpValueCollection, you may need to add a basic collection of some type that is a name/value pair.

Then: populate your new model from the actual request, and serialize your model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the request as a whole (ie: bytes), you can use the [HttpRequest.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filter.aspx). It allows to install a filter (an object that derives from Stream) that can read and write from the raw input HTTP request.

Here is an article on the subject: [Filtering HTTP Requests with .NET](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/10/20/httpfilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but this would likely work and would be available to serialize.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Select(
                    a =>
                        new KeyValuePair<object, object>(a, HttpContext.Current.Request.GetType().GetProperty(a.GetType().Name)))
                .ToList();
```